# I'm trying to use reduce high order function in my javascript code but keeps giving me #<Object> not a function

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm doing an assignment using javascript language for educational purposes, but i'm a beginner. I'm having some problems trying to use reduce function.

What i'm trying to do is to use reduce to filter the following.

"Receive a string array in propNames and an object array in objs. Return a new object array with objects produced by applying the filterProperties function with propNames to each object in objs."

I already code filterProperties and its working fine to match propNames with only one object. I leave the code down below:

```
function filterProperties(propNames, obj) {
    let output = {}
    let objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
    const matchingElems = propNames.sort().filter(elem => objKeys.includes(elem))
    matchingElems.forEach(elem => output[elem] = obj[elem])
    return output
}
```

So just to sum up, i would like to use reduce to iterate and output an array with the properties matching propNames and objs.

My code is not working, i'm a complete beginner and I didn't understand well how to use reduce function. I leave my code below, so that anyone can help me solving this issue.

```
function filterPropertiesN(propNames,objs) {
    objs.reduce(filterProperties(propNames, objs))
 }
```

many thanks in advance!

Comment: You're calling `reduce` on an object. Use an array instead.

Comment: thanks morganney. I have already found a solution.

Comment: @MárioFriande, the purpose of StackOverflow is to create a repository of questions and answers. If you have an answer to your question, it would be good to post it so that the next person with this issue might benefit. 